# GeForce GT 710 Graphics Card duel monitor display causing Monitor 1 of 2 to flicker?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

My System is a dedicated music DAW.

Asus American Megatrends 1905 BIOS

Asus P8H77-V Motherboard

32 gig fast RAM

Windows 7 64 bit (kept updated with all latest appropriate drivers and updates)

3 Samsung Evo Hard Drives

Duel Monitor Display 2xHP w1907v

1 Monitor in to the Grapics Card VGA Port and the other into the DVI-D port via a DVI-D to VGA Adapter.

The windows install has been slim lined taking out bloat ware and system services not needed for audio production and has been stable as a rock and extremely fast.

I have just purchased and installed a ASUS Nvidia GeForce GT 710 Graphics card and I only installed the Graphics Card driver and the HD Audio Driver. I did not need nor want the 3D stuff as I will not use it and it could cause conflicts with my resource hungry soft synths and so on.

Since installing the card the primary monitor (the software sees it as Monitor 1) flickers on and off and when I say flicker I mean the video feed to the monitor and not the mains power.
The feed will be fine for 10 - 15 seconds then will go to black for a second before coming back. In another 30 seconds it happens again, maybe 10 seconds it happens again and so on.
This happens only to the primary monitor (Monitor 1) and Monitor 2 performs perfectly.

This is what I have tried to cure it.
Spoke by web chat to Asus tech support - utterly useless and they admit they have little tech training beyond trying a couple of quick fixes none of which worked. At the tech supports suggestion, I tried moving the GT 710 to my only other PCI slot but it made no difference - the tech support then simply said return it to the place of purchase.

Swapped the video cables around so that Monitor 1's now went to Monitor 2 - no difference
Swapped the cables at the back of the card so the one that was in the VGA port was now in the adapter on the DVI port and the other was now in the VGA - No difference.

Removed the GT 710 from my computer and uninstalled all GeForce software and drivers that came on the install CD.
Plugged each monitor in turn in to the Motherboards own VGA port to test it was not a monitor or cable issue and ran a couple of CPU intensive programs - both monitors performed perfectly.

Downloaded the latest driver set I can find for the GT 710 (431.60-desktop-win8-win7-64bit-international-whql.zip) and performed a clean install for just the Graphics Card driver and the HD Audio only - no difference the issue still happens.

I do not know what else to do - to me this seems like a driver issue but I may be wrong.
The last time I had computer issues, many years ago and several computers back, the issue was caused by bad driver programming and clashing IRQ's.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I think the cause is right there in the question title… the GT 710 is barely powerful enough to light a candle, let alone 2 monitors. Depending on what your CPU is, it may actually be less powerful than your on-chip APU.

Comment: Its the 2 GB DDR3 model - not using it for fancy graphics and it is supposed to be able to handle 3 monitors?